# Find First and Last Number in a Range of Numbers

Tags: vb.net, math, modulo

Imagine a range of numbers from -133 to +71.

I want to find the first and last numbers in the range that divide by 20: in this case it would be -120 and +60.

I can write a For loop that tests each value and stores the required values:

```
Dim resultFirst, resultLast As Integer
Dim FirstFound As Boolean = False
For a As Integer = -133 To 71
    If a Mod 20 = 0 Then
        If FirstFound = False Then
            resultFirst = a
            FirstFound = True
        End If
        resultLast = a
    End If
Next
```

but I suspect there is a simpler formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Range()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range) and the LINQ-methods [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where), [`Min`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.min) and [`Max`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max)

```
Dim resultFirst As Integer
Dim resultLast As Integer
Dim min As Integer = -133
Dim max As Integer = 71
Dim div As Integer = 20

resultFirst = Enumerable.Range(min, max - min + 1).Where(Function(x) x Mod div = 0).Min()
resultLast = Enumerable.Range(min, max - min + 1).Where(Function(x) x Mod div = 0).Max()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to get the first and last value which is dividable by 20:

```
Dim fromValue As Integer = -133
Dim first As Integer = (fromValue - (fromValue Mod 20)) + IIf(fromValue > 0 And fromValue Mod 20 <> 0, 20, 0)

Dim toValue As Integer = 71
Dim last As Integer = (toValue - (toValue Mod 20)) - IIf(toValue < 0 And toValue Mod 20 <> 0, 20, 0)
```

You can also create a function using the above formula:

```
Private Function GetResult(ByVal fromInt As Integer, ByVal toInt As Integer, ByVal divider As Integer) As Integer()

    'set the real from and to value from parameter.
    Dim fromValue As Integer = Math.Min(fromInt, toInt)
    Dim toValue As Integer = Math.Max(fromInt, toInt)

    'get the first and last number dividable by divider between numbers.
    Dim first As Integer = (fromValue - (fromValue Mod divider)) + IIf(fromValue > 0 And fromValue Mod divider <> 0, divider, 0)
    Dim last As Integer = (toValue - (toValue Mod divider)) - IIf(toValue < 0 And toValue Mod divider <> 0, divider, 0)

    If first > toValue Or last < fromValue Then
        Return {}
    Else
        Return {first, last}
    End If
End Function
```

Some test cases for the above function:

```
GetResult(-133, 71, 20)   '0: -120; 1: 60
GetResult(71, -133, 20)   '0: -120; 1: 60
GetResult(100, 119, 20)   '0: 100;  1: 100
GetResult(-113, -112, 20) 'empty array
GetResult(120, 140, 20)   '0: 120;  1: 140
```

Comment: This version is also useful as it can also be converted to floating point numbers: for instance if you wanted to find the first and last points in the range: -133 to 71 that divide by 2.5

Comment: ... this solution is also working since .NET Framework 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
  Dim s As IEnumerable(Of Integer) =
                Enumerable.Range(-133, 133 + 72)

        Dim minV As Integer = s.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(n) n Mod 20 = 0).Min(Function(n) n)

        Dim maxV As Integer = s.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(n) n Mod 20 = 0).Max(Function(n) n)

        Console.WriteLine(minV.ToString() & " " & maxV.ToString())
        Console.ReadLine()
```